# Range of $g(x)=\frac{e^x}{1+\lfloor x\rfloor}$ for $x\ge 0$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

> Find the range of $g(x)=\dfrac{e^x}{1+\lfloor x\rfloor}$ for $x\ge 0$

$$$$
My textbook simply states that since $\dfrac{e^x}{1+\lfloor x\rfloor}$ is an increasing function on $x\in [0,\infty)$, its range is between its minimum and maximum values  ie 
$$$$Range of f is $[f(0), f(x\to \infty))$ or range $\in [1,\infty)$
$$$$
However, from my understanding of the range of a function, the range of a function over an interval $[a,b]$ is the set of all values that $f(x)$ takes for all $x\in [a,b]$. $$$$I believe that the method used in my textbook (of taking the range of a function $f$ as between its maximum and minimum values over an interval $[a,b]$ ) is applicable $only$ when the function is continuous on $[a,b]$, hence ensuring that $f$ takes all possible values between the min and max values of $f$ on $[a,b]$.
$$$$Could somebody please tell me if I am correct in my understanding of when the method is applicable? Also, could somebody please tell me how to find the range of the function $g(x)=\dfrac{e^x}{1+\lfloor x\rfloor}?$

$$$$Many thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct; well spotted. However, the textbook's answer is still right, but not for the reason it gave. The function is not increasing. At the discontinuities it always decreases, so it only ever revisits points.

The function:

- is increasing and continuous on each $[n,n+1)$;
- has each $f(n) < f(n-\epsilon)$;
- has $f(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$;
- has $f(x) \geq 1$ always (though you need to show this).

Together, this is enough to show that the function is surjective onto $[1,\infty)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sir. Sir could you please tell me how to show that $f(x)\ge 1$ always?

Comment: This follows since $1+\lfloor x \rfloor \leq 1+x \leq e^x$.